# solana token program 0xc Invalid Instruction

Tags: spl-token, anchor-client, instructions, typescript, mint

I have recently begun getting the below error when running the `createMint` instruction from `@solana/spl-token`. To my knowledge, I have not changed any code or dependencies that would affect this.

*Example Code*

```
import { PublicKey, Connection, Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";
import * as spl from "@solana/spl-token";

export async function generateMint(
  // I have confirmed that the authority exists and has sufficient funds (1 SOL)
  authority: Keypair,
  connection: Connection
): Promise<Keypair> {
  const mint: Keypair = Keypair.generate();
  try {
    await spl.createMint(
      connection,
      authority,
      authority.publicKey,
      authority.publicKey,
      9,
      mint
    );

  } catch (e) {
    console.trace(e)
    throw e
  }

  return mint;
}
```

*Error*

```
Trace: SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0xc
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/path/to/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5054:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Connection.sendRawTransaction (/path/to/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5013:20)
    at Connection.sendTransaction (/path/to/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5001:12)
    at sendAndConfirmTransaction (/path/to/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/utils/send-and-confirm-transaction.ts:31:21) {
  logs: [
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Error: Invalid instruction',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 796 of 1400000 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: custom program error: 0xc'
  ]
}
```

*Context*

- OS Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (WSL 2)
- @project-serum/anchor: 0.25.0
- @solana/spl-token: 0.3.5
- invoking command: `anchor test` (== `yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts`)

Comment: I can't say specifically why this fails but this is the preferred way of creating an spl token(according to the spl docs): ```
let mint = await spl.createMint( connection, authority, authority.publicKey, authority.publicKey, 9
); return mint;
```

Comment: I just tested my code sample for creating a mint using the JS library with no issues. What Solana network cluster are you connecting to?

Comment: I'm using localnet, running tests for my program using `anchor test`

Comment: That could be the issue. The version of the Token program could be different between your localnet and the devnet/production version. Try running your same code on devnet. There are currently changes in the works for the SPL token program and token swap program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading `@solana/spl-token` to `0.2.0` worked. I guess anchor is not up to date with solana...?

Comment: This is a workaround, not an answer.