# @solana/spl-token createMint() is broken with custom program error: 0xc / Invalid instruction after version 0.34

Tags: spl-token

> Note there's a similar question at [solana token program 0xc Invalid Instruction](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3968/solana-token-program-0xc-invalid-instruction) - but the 'answer' is to simply downgrade metaplex. I (and probably many other people on Solana) would like to use fixes in current version of metaplex

I'm using `createMint()` from `@solana/spl-token` 0.3.4 and it works fine:

```
import { createMint } from "@solana/spl-token";
const mintAccountPublicKey = await createMint(
  connection,
  payer,
  mintAuthority,
  null, 
  decimals
);
```

Again, **this works fine** and creates a mint.

When I upgrade `@solana/spl-token` to 0.3.5 (or upgrade Metaplex which upgrades spl-token) `createMint()` breaks:

```
ERRROR failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0xc
```

I know from [error.rs](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/cd8d79a2b4aa4f90c02514d762ab21023449b6cb/token/program/src/error.rs#L9) that 0xc is `Invalid instruction`.

**Update**: **[I have filed the bug with spl](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues/4051)**. Also note this question was originally tagged with metaplex - the issue only relates to metaplex because metaplex updates spl-token to 0.3.5 or newer. I have removed the metaplex tag as metaplex is not at fault, and edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Answering my own question to help others. Thanks to [joncinque](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues/4051) for solving this.*

**You need to regularly update your local validator**, which includes a newer version of the Solana and the spl-token on-chain programs, to match your `@solana/web3.js` and `@solana/spl-token` updates.

```
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
⠤ Initializing...
Identity: HATCjKKDuCS547rmVH1t31zpiJShXnffRqLwR8fAYwZC
Genesis Hash: 82Qc3cFQUTDCYfLZEDGynywx2EhXzeHat4G1bWQV6pg7
Version: 1.9.30
```

1.9.30 is too old. You can see the current version of Solana used in production with the command `solana validators`:

```
Stake By Version:
1.15.3  -    0 current validators ( 0.00%)   1 delinquent validators ( 0.00%)
1.15.2  -    0 current validators ( 0.00%)   1 delinquent validators ( 0.01%)
1.15.1  -    0 current validators ( 0.00%)   1 delinquent validators ( 0.02%)
1.15.0  -    1 current validators ( 0.02%)
1.14.15 -  435 current validators (10.35%)  29 delinquent validators ( 0.30%)
1.14.13 -    4 current validators ( 0.05%)   4 delinquent validators ( 0.00%)
1.14.11 -    1 current validators ( 0.00%)
1.14.10 -    1 current validators ( 0.01%)
1.14.5  -    0 current validators ( 0.00%)   5 delinquent validators ( 0.09%)
1.13.7  -    1 current validators ( 0.13%)
1.13.6  - 1199 current validators (32.70%)  34 delinquent validators ( 0.26%)
1.13.5  -  723 current validators (54.54%)  20 delinquent validators ( 0.04%)
1.13.4  -   10 current validators ( 0.53%)   1 delinquent validators ( 0.02%)
1.13.3  -   12 current validators ( 0.36%)
1.13.1  -    0 current validators ( 0.00%)   1 delinquent validators ( 0.00%)
1.9.12  -    0 current validators ( 0.00%)   1 delinquent validators ( 0.00%)
1.8.14  -    0 current validators ( 0.00%)   1 delinquent validators ( 0.00%)
unknown -    1 current validators ( 0.00%) 614 delinquent validators ( 0.56%)
```

After [upgrading](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools):

```
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
⠁ Initializing...
Waiting for fees to stabilize 1...
Identity: 6uDKZaJJyYdJ2m12DJZAoqfhoshfSXCgRxxz8DswNgwZ
Genesis Hash: 8borh5LdxMdB126h4pX1sisEMANqAeeueEkiSDvJcBRx
Version: 1.15.2
```

And re-running the test above, 1.15.2 solves the problem.